# alternate of cbind and rbind in loop

Tags: r

I am generating some variables in a loop which I later store into a dataframe one line at a time. I feel that I am using too much of cbind and rbind which is making the code inefficient. What is an alternative to the following structure.

```
Sys.time()
outData = c()
for (i in 1:40000)
{
  a=0; b=0; c=0;d=0;e=0;f=0;g=0
  #newline = cbind(a,cbind(b,cbind(c,cbind(d,cbind(e,f)))))
  newline = do.call(cbind, list(a,b,c,d,e,f,g))
  outData = rbind(outData, newline)
}
Sys.time()
```

Edit:
do.call() seems to be slower here.

Comment: seems you need something like `do.call(cbind,...)` but you should clarify your question..

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. Needs to have better problem description and test data supplied.

Comment: what are you actually putting into a, b, c, etc?  Surely not 0's.  I would be surprised if there is not a way to `lapply` this in one shot

Comment: it is a mix of long text and numbers.

Comment: Are those vectors or single values (as in your example)? Please describe what you actually want to do. Certainly you don't want a data.frame with only zeros. And of course you should pre-allocate if you want to use a `for` loop (but there are probably better alternatives anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT  Based on the new code in the OP:

You dont even need `cbind`.  just whatever you are assigning to a, b, c, d... pyt that right into a data.frame.  or at the very worst

```
newline=data.frame(a,b,c,d...,etc)
```

---

The inefficiencies are most likely coming from generating i==1000 single row data.frames one at a time.   There is likely a much more effective solution.

With regards to the complex cbind line, try the following instead:

```
    #instead of:
    newline = cbind(a,cbind(b,cbind(.......z,cbind(a1,a2))))))

    # try: 
    newline = do.call(cbind, list(a, b, ..., z))
```

Comment: thanks. I tried the code but `do.call` seems to be slower alternate. but it is much more convenient for sure

Comment: are you sure you want to _`cbind`_ them??  Maybe you mean `rbind`? In which case you can use rbindlist from the data.table package

Comment: Yes, Basically I am populating values from other computations and consolidating those into a table.